# example, that Wilson's Theorem is not necessarily true

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Show by an example, that Wilson's Theorem is not necessarily true if $p$ is not prime. (In fact, it is not hard to show that it is never true if $p$ is not prime, but I am not asking you to do that.)

My solve :
let $p$ is not prime like $4$ so $(4 - 1)! = 3!  = 2 \pmod 4 \neq -1 \pmod 4$.

Is that correct?

Comment: $3!$ is not $0$ $\pmod 4$.

Comment: $3!=6\equiv 2\mod 4$

Comment: You have the right idea: you need to show that the statement is not *always* true by finding an example, and $4$ is the smallest example (since it is the smallest composite integer).

Comment: $(6-1)!\equiv 5!\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. We have $(n-1)!\equiv 0\pmod{n}$ for all composite $n\ge 6$. We have that $n=4$ is the only composite positive integer for which $(n-1)!\not\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

Comment: Huh? Wilson's theorem is an "if and only if" statement, and it is always true.

Comment: Let $n\ge 6$ be a composite integer. I'll prove that $(n-1)!\equiv 0\pmod{n}$.

Let $n=ab$ for some $a\ge b\ge 2$. If $a\neq b$, then

$2\le b< a<2a-1\le ab-1= n-1$, so $ab=n\mid (n-1)!$.

If $a=b$, then $n=a^2\ge 6$, so $a\ge 3$, so

$2\le a<2a<3a-1\le a^2-1=n-1$, so $a\cdot 2a=2n\mid (n-1)!$.

Comment: @bof When I learned Wilson's theorem it was presented as an "if $p$ is prime" statement, and I would argue that this comprises the heart of the theorem.  It has the feel of an "if" that can be strengthened to "iff" by some tedious calculation (or further strengthened to an exact formula).  The use of $p$ rather than $n$ in many formulations of Wilson's theorem mildly reinforces this perception.

Comment: Hmmm, $0! \equiv -1 \pmod 1$, so one should be careful about saying it is **never** true when $p$ is not prime.

Comment: @ErickWong Anyway, Wilson's theorem is true, and there can be no counterexample to a true statement. A counterexample to Wilson's theorem would be a number $p$ such that $p$ is prime but $(p-1)!+1$ is not divisible by $p.$ A counterexample to an erroneous generalization of Wilson's theorem is not a counterexample to Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

As Mr. Brooks pointed out, Wilson's theorem is an if-and-only-if theorem, which makes it different from Fermat's little theorem. Fermat's condition holds for all primes and some composites, so the fact that a given number satisfies the condition is not a guarantee of primality.

By contrast, a number that meets Wilson's condition is guaranteed to be a prime number. (However, the calculations are more laborious, which diminishes the practical value of Wilson's theorem).

So, if I understand your question correctly, you can choose any composite number $n$ (preferably a small one, like 4) and do the calculations to show that $(n - 1)! \equiv 2$ or $0 \pmod n$.

But maybe what you're looking for is something a little bit more general that still stops short of proving the whole theorem.

For example, if $n$ is an even composite number, then $(n - 1)!$ is also an even composite number. If $(n - 1)! \equiv -1 \pmod n$, that would mean $(n - 1)!$ is odd, which is a contradiction.

Or let's say $n = pq$, the product of two distinct odd primes. Since $p < q < n$ (or $q < p < n$, doesn't make much difference), it follows that both $p$ and $q$ are divisors of $(n - 1)!$. Therefore $(n - 1)! \equiv 0$, not $-1$, $\pmod n$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem a little confused about what Wilson's theorem is, so before going any further, let's straighten that out. According to Mathworld, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WilsonsTheorem.html Wilson's theorem states that if *and only if* $p$ is prime is $(p - 1)! + 1$ a multiple of $p$, or the congruence $(p - 1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$ is true if and only if $p$ is prime.

What you are being asked to come up with is a specific example to show that $(p - 1)! \not\equiv -1 \pmod p$ when $p$ is not prime. You have already done that with $p = 4$.

Comment: You were doing very well until you got into that $qs$ stuff.

Comment: I'll comment it out for now.